# Windows batch: for and findstr to include and exclude from results

Tags: windows, batch-file, findstr

I have a list of strings I'm iterating over, and I need to exclude certain ones and include others in the subsequent processing.
Something like this:

```
listmystuff | for /F "usebackq" %%D in (`findstr /r "something*" ^| findstr /v "but not thisstuff"`)  do interestingthing
```

This is wrong.  What does work is having one of the findstr's but not both.
What would be right?

Comment: What error do you get?  Show an example of your input if it is still failing.

Comment: I'm still getting the "| was unexpected at this time" error when I have two findstr's

Comment: My input is piped from a mysql "show databases" command.

Answer (score 2):

You want a pipe `|`, not conditional command concatenation `&&`. The pipe character must be escaped.

You only want one set of single quotes around the entire commmand. (or backticks if using `usebackq` option)

You need to double the percents if used within a batch file.

Your initial FINDSTR needs a filespec to search (or else data piped into it)

```
for /f "options" %%D in ('findstr "something" fileSpec ^| findstr /v "butNotThis"') do myThing
```

Comment: I am using "usebackq"! I tried this but got "| was unexpected at this time."?

Comment: @iss42 - Did you remember to escape the pipe as `^|`? It should work.

Comment: yip I did, I also have `findstr /r "something*"` using the wildcard, but no `fileSpec`, maybe thats the issue? What is `fileSpec`?

Comment: @iss42 - fileSpec represents the file(s) you want to search. You definitely want one, but the absence will not cause that error. Edit your question to include the exact statement that is failing.

Answer (score 0):

Give this a run with your show databases command.  This is the usual way to use a for command to parse data.

```
for /F "delims=" %%D in ('show databases ^| findstr /r "something*" ^| findstr /v /c:"but not thisstuff" ')  do echo %%D
```

Comment: I don't understand the "file.txt" part, I don't have a file? I am piping data to this find if that helps.

Comment: findstr normally takes data from a file, or through a preceding pipe.  But the code works fine if I remove `"file.txt"` and pipe data through the batch file.

Comment: I'm still getting the "| was unexpected at this time" error when I have two findstr's

Comment: I've got a command that lists database names, the output of this I am piping to the for.  It also works just fine as long as I don't have more than one findstr condition within the for "in".

Comment: If you want to `pipe into a for` command then you have to accept that it is not supported by Microsoft and that anything that results from it is more from luck than good design. :)